# Purpose of overloading member function returning iterator and const_iterator

Tags: c++

In my class assignment I am suppose to implement member functions of a predefined class. I am confused on the purpose of these the overload on findStudent. Can this class not be designed to only contain one definition, which returns a regular iterator that can be casted as const? Or rather, use std::find since it is already overloaded to return a const_iterator?

```
class Class{
public:
   Class(std::string name, std::string teacher, std::string capacity);
   std::string getTeacher();
   std::string getName();
   int getCapacity();
   void addStudent(std::string);
   void removeStudent(std::string);
   std::vector<std::string>::iterator findStudent();
   std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator findStudent() const;
private:
   std::string name;
   std::string teacher;
   int capacity;
   std::vector<std::string> students;
};
```

Comment: You cannot have (non template)overloads which differ only by return type, don't you forget `const` for later method?

Comment: "iterator that can be casted as const?" - whenever you use a cast you are either *very sure* of what you are doing and *know* that viewing that thing as some other thing still makes sense, *or* you are writing a bug. Be *extremely* careful when using casts.

Comment: Yes i did, it shoudl be std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator findStudent() const;. This is only a rough copy of what I was given by my prof. I really just want to know the purpose of why there are two functions with identical names differing by return type. Typically my functions are overloaded to take different types of parameters

Comment: You cannot overload on return type only in C++.

Comment: If this is not an overload then what is this? 2 identical methods with different return types? How do i implement this?

Comment: @ben No, he's saying it would be illegal without the `const`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of overloading those functions is that they differ by their *const*-ness.

Consider:

you pass `Class foo;` to a function

`void bar(Class& foo)`.

If inside this function you were to call `findStudent()`, the non-const version of the member function would be invoked. As a result, you would get a *mutating* iterator of `std::vector<std::string>`. The iterator would allow to assign new values, clear strings and do whatever else you want with the values.

Now consider another case:

`void bar(const Class& foo)`.

Inside this function, the const version of `findStudents()` will be called, and you won't be able to modify the values. You will be able to inspect them, to print them, to sum the lengths, i.e., you will be able to do only *non-mutating* operations on your students.

The purpose of this is to enable both the compiler and -- especially important! -- the programmer to reason about the code. Const functions do not change the state of the object, they conserve invariants of the code. For instance, it generally holds that if you call a const function twice in succession, both calls should return the same answer. (This holds "generally", but not always, especially if we are dealing with hardware).

Answer (score 0):

When a member function is const-qualified, it can be called on a const object.  (It can also be called on a non-const object, since a const conversion that ADDs const is a valid implicit conversion.)

Member functions that are not const qualified can only be called on non-const objects (because they can change the state of the object, defeating the meaning of const if such a conversion could happen.)

Thus:

```
class Foo {
public:
...
    int& operator[](int idx) { return values[idx]; }       // 1
    int operator[](int idx) const { return values[idx]; }  // 2
private:
    int values[10];
};
```

We have two versions of `operator[]`, one returning a mutable reference, and the other returning a copy (on which changes won't affect the object it came from.

And so

```
Foo f;
int& x = f[3]; // calls 1, since f is non-const

const Foo cf;
int y = cf[3]; // calls 2, since cf is const
```

If you want your code to work on const and non-const objects, but always return a const_iterator, then you could get by with only implementing a version of `findStudent` that has the const qualification, like op 2 does above, and not overload it with the non-const version.

I am guessing that findStudent is supposed to take a name (or other criteria) and return an iterator to that student, or an "end" iterator if it's not found.  In that case, you'd use std::find() in the implementation of find_student.  So be sure to allow callers to say what student they want to find!